# XeLaTex: -- sign

Tags: xetex, punctuation

I use following code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[]{llcl}
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}\textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Description} \\\hline
-c, --create & Do something\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

So after I created the PDF document, the "--" is converted to:

> -create

Is there any possibility to fix that, because I need both "-".

Comment: Add an empty group between the two hyphens: `-{}-`

Comment: You can avoid XeTeX joining the two hyphens into an en-dash by loading the font without the `Ligatures=TeX` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an empty group between the two hyphens:

```
   \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}[]{llcl}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}\textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Description} \\\hline
    -c, -{}-create & Do something\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

Thank you lockstep for you answer!